# HYPERLINK formula field in Lightning

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm trying to create a formula field which shows up on the default page layout as a link. It works wonderfully in salesforce classic but some default behavior is breaking it in Lightning mode.

My formula field definition looks like:

```
HYPERLINK( 
'/apex/MY_VF_PAGE?cid='&Id, 
'LINK_TEXT'
)
```

In lightning mode the field is being rendered as:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ontouchstart="javascript:{ var openEvent = $A.get('e.force:navigateToURL');  openEvent.setParams({'url':'/apex/MY_VF_PAGE_HERE?cid=50061000000t04z'});openEvent.fire();}" data-aura-rendered-by="291:383;a">LINK_TEXT</a>
```

I could be wrong, but I believe the cause of the problem is the 'ontouchstart' event that's generated. I came to this conclusion when I log into Salesforce1 on my phone, it works perfectly. But, as I'm sure you understand, I don't want the functionality of my page limited to mobile. Is there any workaround for this? Or possible solution? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this is a [current Limitation](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_gaps_limitations_productivity.htm) with Lightning Experience

> Hyperlink formula fields are not supported.

and there is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jYhZAAU) which is planned to be fixed in Spring 16 (safe harbor).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Hopefully they roll this out with the Spring 16 release. Good to know I'm not the only one with this issue.